# Is there a better way to make nested calls to Firebase Database with Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase as my backend and am finding myself frequently nesting calls such as this:

```
    fun getAllItemsFromDb() {
    databaseService.apply {
        getFavoritesData { favorites ->
            getItemCategories { items->
                if (items.isNotEmpty()) {
                    getAllItemsBySection(categories, favorites) { sectionData ->
                        _itemsBySection.value = sectionData
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I could instead make these calls asynchronously and only process the data on successful completion of all three calls instead of chaining them like this?

Or, if not, is there a better way to make these kinds of nested calls?

Update: For reference, here are the 2 functions for getting favorites and items

```
    fun getFavoritesData(favoritesResult: (List<String>?) -> Unit) {
    if (firebaseAuth.currentUser != null) {
        databaseReference.child("favorites").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val result = snapshot.value as ArrayList<*>?

                favoritesResult(result?.map { it as String })

                Log.d("Firebase", "getFavs:Success")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("Firebase", "getFavs:Failure")
            }
        })
    }
}

    fun getItemCategories(categoriesRetrieved: (List<Any>) -> Unit) {
    databaseReference.child("categories").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
        ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val result = snapshot.value as ArrayList<*>?
            result?.let { categoriesRetrieved(it) }
            Log.d("Firebase", "getItemCategories:Success")
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Firebase", "getItemCategories:Failure")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, for sure there is but it's hard to provide a solution based only on the shared code.

Comment: Please see the updated examples, let me know if there's anything else I can provide!

Comment: Is onDataChange even triggered? How about onCancelled?

Comment: Yes, on data changed is hit. I should probably change this to just a success listener though. Something I've seen before with network calls is to call them in something like this: Observable.latest(call1, call2) { result1, result2-> callback1(result1, result2)  } then make the next call through the callback. This is incredibly vague, but I was hoping to combine the calls in a similar fashion.

Comment: If onDataChange fires, it means that you're able to get the data. In such case, what's the issue?

Comment: There's no problem with this code, everything works correctly. I was hoping for a cleaner way to combine these calls. It looks like I could use RxJava or Flows to get the data and combine the streams. Not sure what the pros of going with coroutines or Rx is compared to what I have though.